# NetBeans cannot detect data created from Oracle XE 11g

Tags: jdbc

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try {
        String a = jTextField1.getText().trim();
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "SYSTEM", "tiger");
        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("Select * from EMS.EMP where 'ENo'=?");
        pst.setString(1, a);
        ResultSet r = pst.executeQuery();
        String s = "Status:";
        if (r.next()) {
            s = s + "\nName: " + r.getString(2);
            s = s + "\nAddress: " + r.getString(3);
            s = s + "\nDesignation: " + r.getString(4);
            s = s + "\nSSN: " + r.getString(5);
            s = s + "\nDepartment Number: " + r.getString(6);
            s = s + "\nBasic Pay: " + r.getString(7);
        } else
            s = s + "Record is not found";
        conn.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, s);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

This is my code snippet for searching a particular employee detail..

But I am getting **"Record is not found"** as output even though the record actually exists in the oracle database table.

This is my first project so any help would be appreciated..

**Am i missing any code line?**

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in your SQL string:

```
    "Select * from EMS.EMP where 'ENo'=?"
```

This will return everything from `EMS.EMP` if the value assigned to the bind parameter is the string `ENo`, and nothing otherwise.

The reason is that in SQL, `'ENo'` is a string literal, it means "just the text `ENo`".  I imagine there is a column in your table named `ENo` and you want to filter by values in this column. In this case, you should either remove the single quotes:

```
    "Select * from EMS.EMP where ENo=?"
```

or use double quotes (depending on how your table was created):

```
    "Select * from EMS.EMP where \"ENo\"=?"
```

(The double-quotes around `ENo` need to be backslash-escaped as they are within a Java string.)